# Yii JWPlayer playlist issue

Tags: php, video, yii, jwplayer, playlist

I am still new to Yii. I need a video player in the website I am designing, so I just get JWPlayer for yii from below :
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ejwplayer/

I am able to put a single video in my Yii application using the `filepath` option, but I want to put more than only one video. The example of playlist does not work for me, but I really need the playlist !

My videos are in a videos folder(www.myWebsite.com/htdocs/videos).

Comment: I never never used Yii before. Do you have a link to where this is not working?